# C++, NULL != 0xcdcdcdcd

Tags: c++, null

I'm having problems with this while loop. Even when the variable is 0xcdcdcdcd the loop will keep on going and crash. My question is what is the difference between NULL and 0xcdcdcdcd and how can i check for the end of the list. Thanks!.
Also, I'm initializing p->next_ to NULL in the constructor.

```
void node::showList() const{
  const node *p = this;
  std::cout << "LIST ----------------------------- " << std::endl;
  while( p != NULL ){
    std::cout << p->data_;
    p = p->next_;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect NULL to be 0xcdcdcdcd?

Comment: `0xcdcdcdcd` is a value some debuggers (such as MSVC's, I believe) assign to pointers which you haven't initialised. `NULL` is usually represented as `0`, but that's not mandatory. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), there is not enough information to answer this as-is.

Comment: You have to put a NULL (or 0 it's the same) at the end of you chained list. 0xcdcdcdcd denotes an uninitialized field.

Comment: I'd vote against closing. The problem is obvious and correct comments have been posted.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I found the mistake, i had 2 constructors and the second one didn't set next_ to NULL. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

NULL isn't 0xcdcdcdcd. 0xcdcdcdcd has no special significance. If you want a null pointer, use NULL or (in C++11) nullptr.